# Passing multiple parameter to PHP from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

i am trying to Use this

```
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return null;
}

function CallSomePHP()
{
    xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp==null)
    {
    alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
    return;
    }
    var url="myPhp.php"; ***(Need to Pass multiple parameter to php from here)***
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Comment: You can post code using code blocks to lay it out much neater with lines and spacing.  It's the button that looks like binary code `101010` just above the edit box. (alternatively, insert 4 spaces before each line of code)

Answer (score 5):

This is really easy:

```
var url="myPhp.php?param1="+ param1 + "&param2=" + param2
```

However you might consider using jQuery.

As it would become even easier ;)

To have a complete ajax call you need only one method call without having to care about browser issues. So your code becomes a lot easier to read.

```
 $.ajax({
   // you can use post and get:
   type: "POST",
   // your url
   url: "some.php",
   // your arguments
   data: {name : "John", location : "Boston"},
   // callback for a server message:
   success: function( msg ){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   },
   // callback for a server error message or a ajax error
   error: function( msg )
   {
     alert( "Data was not saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

You add them to the URL string, so:

```
var url="myPhp.php?a=1&b=2&c=3";
```

then you can access them in PHP from the $_GET array:

```
$Param1 = $_GET['a']; // = 1
$Param2 = $_GET['b']; // = 2
$Param3 = $_GET['c']; // = 3
```