# Passing Data from Javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, data-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing multiple parameter to PHP from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600360/passing-multiple-parameter-to-php-from-javascript)

I am currently trying to pass data from Javascript to PHP.  I have the PHP script is accessed from the Javascript except no information is stored in the `$_Post` variable. I even tried the `$_Get` and the `$_Request` to make sure it was not stored there.  It was not. Can someone please help me?  The function that I am using is below.  The variable str is a string of things that I create elsewhere in the javascript that I feel as though are not useful to see.  They are not gotten from an HTML form.  The PHP script is also below.
Thanks

Javascript function that is supposed to do the passing of information.

```
function postForm(str) {
  var xmlHttp;
  try
    {    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
     xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {    // Internet Explorer    
      try
      {
       xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");      
      } catch (e)
        {      
         try
         {
          xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (e)
           {       
             alert("ERROR: CAN NOT POST DATA");
           }
        }
    }

    try 
    {
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
        {
         alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
      }
       xmlHttp.open("POST","BigInt2.php",true);
       postStr = "msg="+escape(str);
       alert("SENDING: "+postStr);
       xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xmlHttp.send(postStr);
    } catch(e)
      {
       alert("ERROR POSTING DATA");
      } 

}
```

PHP function that is supposed to do the printing of infomration as a proof of concept that the information is stored in the $_Post global variable.
BigInt2.php

```
<?php
echo$_Post['msg'];
echo$_Get['msg'];
echo$_Request['msg'];
?>
```

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason you don't want to.. use jQuery. It makes this stuff so much simpler.

Comment: its POST and GET ..not Post and Get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mistyping (post and get) try this in your php file and see if it works

```
echo $_POST['msg'];
```

Comment: Oops...I had a senior moment there haha